# Using Enumerable.Aggregate(...) Method over an empty sequence

Tags: c#, linq, sequence, aggregate

I would like to use the *Enumerable.Aggregate(...)* method to concatenate a list of strings separated by a semicolon. Rather easy, isn't it?

Considering the following:

- `private const string LISTSEPARATOR = "; ";`
- *album.**OrderedTracks*** is `List<TrackDetails>`
- *TrackDetails* has *DiscNumber* Int16? property

The following statement will trow an exception if the sequence returned by *Distinct()* is empty (as the *Aggregate()* method doesn't apply on empty sequence):

```
    txtDiscNumber.Text = album.OrderedTracks
        .Where(a => a.DiscNumber.HasValue)
        .Select(a => a.DiscNumber.Value.ToString())
        .Distinct()
        .Aggregate((i, j) => i + LISTSEPARATOR + j);
```

The workaround I am using:

```
    List<string> DiscNumbers = 
        album.OrderedTracks
            .Where(a => a.DiscNumber.HasValue)
            .Select(a => a.DiscNumber.Value.ToString())
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

    if (!DiscNumbers.Any())
        txtDiscNumber.Text = null;
    else
        txtDiscNumber.Text = 
            DiscNumbers.Aggregate((i, j) => i + LISTSEPARATOR + j);
```

Is there any better solution? Is it possible to do this in a single LINQ statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aggregate, in general, is not a good idea for dealing with aggregating strings, because concating strings is not a cheap operation, and it scales very poorly.  If you're going to do this yourself you should be using something like a `StringBuilder`, although in your specific case you can use `String.Join`, which will internally avoid excessive string concatenation, so not only does it handle this edge case better, but it will perform *much* better for non-trivial data sets.

Answer (score 49):

To concatenate a list of strings, use the [`string.Join`](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=string.join&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx&ei=zEkeUcOqNIqF4gSjgIGIBw&usg=AFQjCNHE5gRaqjGjfYh-n85NvDNBnKAL-g&sig2=p8cwzKlFtJQBbvL1FKgoBQ&bvm=bv.42553238,d.bGE) method.

The `Aggregate` function doesn't work with empty collections. It requires a binary accumulate function and it needs an item in the collection to pass to the binary function as a seed value.

However, there is an [overload of `Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548744.aspx):

```
public static TResult Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func,
    Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

This overload allows you to specify a seed value. If a seed value is specified, it will also be used as the result if the collection is empty.

**EDIT:** If you'd really want to use `Aggregate`, you can do it this way:

```
sequence.Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, y) => x == string.Empty ? y : x + Separator + y)
```

Or this way by using `StringBuilder`:

```
sequence.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, x) => (sb.Length == 0 ? sb : sb.Append(Separator)).Append(x)).ToString()
```

Comment: Please note that if you use the seed value, it will appear at the begining of the result string: `;item1;item2`

Answer (score 12):

I think you might find the following helper extension method useful.

```
public static TOut Pipe<TIn, TOut>(this TIn _this, Func<TIn, TOut> func)
{
    return func(_this);
}
```

It allows you to express your query in the following way.

```
txtDiscNumber.Text = album.OrderedTracks
    .Where(a => a.DiscNumber.HasValue)
    .Select(a => a.DiscNumber.Value.ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .Pipe(items => string.Join(LISTSEPARATOR, items));
```

This still reads "top to bottom," which greatly aids readability.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```cs
.Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, name) => acc + (acc.Length > 0 ? separator : string.Empty) + name)
```

with the initial value it works for empty collections but it's not pretty with the length check

Comment: This is the actual answer for how to use Aggregate for this. Yes Join is better in this very specific situation, but not really the question

Comment: This will prepend a LISTSEPARATOR before any other value.

Comment: you're right, I've updated it with the length check

Answer (score 7):

Use `String.Join` like this:

```
 txtDiscNumber.Text = String.Join(LISTSEPARATOR,
      album.OrderedTracks
                  .Where(a => a.DiscNumber.HasValue)
                  .Select(a => a.DiscNumber.Value.ToString())
                  .Distinct());
```

Answer (score -1):

Used methods like that a lot for debugging purposes, 
came up with two extension-methods:

```
public static string Concatenate<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, U> selector, string separator = ", ")
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return source
        .Select(selector)
        .Concatenate(separator);
}

public static string Concatenate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string separator = ", ")
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool firstPass = true;
    foreach (string item in source.Distinct().Select(x => x.ToString()))
    {
        if (firstPass)
        {
            firstPass = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(separator);
        }

        sb.Append(item);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Use like this:

```
string myLine = myCol.Concatenate(x => x.TheProperty);
```